# Need to disconnect Authenticator App via Apex

Tags: apex, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

Right now we can disconnect authenticator for a user from user record where we see this setting:

```
App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator
```

Can we do the same operation from Apex?

Comment: This is possibly an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why do you need to do this in Apex? What else have you tried?

Comment: @sfdcfox Interesting website, where can I find more like that?

Comment: @compski I'm not sure how people find these things. I guess they show up organically in comment sections and blogs, etc. Another one that's common on [so] is the [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/), describing how to make a post that has enough information to be useful (code-wise). If you spend enough time on [so], you're bound to run into others.